# Binding to change of external model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone view with a model.

Additionally I have a global model holding some application specific stuff.

Now I'm binding the change event of this model to my view's render method but this doesn't seem to work.

```
model: new Preferences.Item(),

render: function() {

    $(that.el).html(template(that.model.toJSON()));                 
},

initialize : function() {
        this.render = _.bind(this.render, this);
        // global account model holder
            App.Storage.account.bind("change", this.render);
},
```

Must I do some specific binding to attach to the events of an external model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution ... you must call:

```
App.Storage.account.on("change", this.render)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `render` method with using Backbone's inline binding. Also, you used `that` in your `render` method, it will be an error about it.

```js
var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Preferences.Item(),
    template: _.template('<div><%= variable %></div>');
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
    },
    initialize: function () {
        App.Storage.account.on('change', this.render, this);
    }
});
```